# Is the space of $\sigma$-finite measures measurable?

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space. There is a natural $\sigma$-algebra on the space of all measures on $\mathcal{F}$, defined as being generated by all maps $\mu\mapsto\mu(A)$ with $A\in\mathcal{F}$. It is obvious that, for instance, the set of probability measures and the set of all finite measures on $\mathcal{F}$ are both elements of this $\sigma$-algebra. Is the same true of the $\sigma$-finite measures? I suspect not but don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, if we take $\Omega$ to be the set of all measures on $\mathcal{F}$, then the $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ that we're talking about is generated by the collection of evaluation functions $f_{A} \colon \Omega \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ with $f_{A}(\mu) = \mu(A)$, for $A \in \mathcal{F}$?

Comment: Yes. In Kallenberg's "Foundations of modern probability" this is how a sigma-algebra is defined on the space of sigma-finite measures. (I don't know why he restricts to that class)

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that if $\mathcal{F}$ is big enough, then the set of $\sigma$-finite measures shouldn't be in this $\sigma$-algebra. However, I also don't know how to prove it. Maybe an example will give someone some inspiration, or maybe I'll come up with some real progress later.

If $X = \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, then every measure $\mu$ on $(X, \mathcal{F})$ is completely determined by its values on each $\{n\}$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In particular, a measure $\mu$ here is $\sigma$-finite if and only if $\mu(\{n\}) < \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, using the notation in my comment to the question,
$$
\{\mu : \mu \text{ is } \sigma \text{-finite}\} 
= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_{\{n\}}^{-1}([0, \infty)),
$$
which is a member of our $\sigma$-algebra since it's a countable intersection of sets in our $\sigma$-algebra.